# Can someone point out the errors in this code?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner python programmer trying to execute this code but I don't quite know the def function all that well yet... can someone point out the errors in my code and how to fix them?

```
import math


def main():
    radius = get_radius()
    calculate = cal_volume()
    dis = display()

def get_radius():
    rad = float(input("Enter the radius :"))
    return rad

def cal_volume(radius):
    return 4/3*math.pi*radius**3

def display(cal_volume):
    print("The volume is :",cal_volume)

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide parameters for `cal_volume()` and `display()` in your `def main()`.

It should be:

```
import math


def main():
    radius = get_radius()
    calculate = cal_volume(radius)
    dis = display(calculate)
    # print out the result?

def get_radius():
    rad = float(input("Enter the radius :"))
    return rad

def cal_volume(radius):
    return 4/3*math.pi*radius**3

def display(cal_volume):
    print("The volume is :",cal_volume)

main()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It really helps alot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import math

def main():
    radius = get_radius()
    calculate = cal_volume(radius)
    dis = display(calculate)

def get_radius():
    rad = float(input("Enter the radius :"))
    return rad

def cal_volume(radius):
    return 4/3*math.pi*radius**3

def display(cal_volume):
    print("The volume is :",cal_volume)

main()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!